# JPL for java\prolog

Tags: java, prolog

I'm interested in using JPL with java, but an error message is prompting like 'package jpl does not exist' while trying to compile the java program. How do i import jpl to java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the JPL package/s , then make it accessible to your class(I'm not exactly sure where to put it, but probably in the /lib of your java directory) . **See here** : http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable

More info: [How to use JPL (bidirectional Java/Prolog interface) on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914495/how-to-use-jpl-bidirectional-java-prolog-interface-on-windows)

Comment: the link you posted has the download link to jpl but that is not working.

Comment: do i need to download swi-prolog from here>

Comment: Yes, this is it! Choose your OS . BTW please vote up for me :)

Comment: Thanks! Ok if it's installed you just need to find the package, then import it correctly in your Java class.

Comment: thats what my problem is...though i have the jpl package, i'm still facing the error called  'package jpl does not exist'

Comment: Try this for help - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=282429   this - http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/105863   . basically I think you need to find your "build path" , add the external jar files.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `sudo apt-get install swi-prolog` and then `sudo apt-get install swi-prolog-java`