# How to use JPL (bidirectional Java/Prolog interface) on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I'm interested in embedding a Prolog interpreter in Java. One option is using JPL, but the download links on the JPL site are broken, and the installation page mentions a jpl.zip that I can't find. I downloaded SWI-Prolog which seems to include JPL (it lists it as a component when installing), but I'm still not sure how I'd use it along with Java.

Any ideas on how to use JPL on Linux? Is there another library I could use to achieve the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start here: [JPL for java\prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558418/jpl-for-java-prolog) (the important is "sudo apt-get install swi-prolog and then sudo apt-get install swi-prolog-java").

And if you use Netbeans as IDE, you have to add the JPL.jar library to your project (that comes with the installation of swi-prolog-java: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/jpl.jar). Then you have to configure the execution options (project properties - run) by adding:

-Djava.library.path = / usr / lib / swi-prolog / lib / (amd64 or i386, depending on your architecture).